# AEM Slightly - How to call java method whose name is stored in variable - expression inside expression doesn’t work in sightly

Tags: aem, sightly

In sightly I have initialized the sling model class. Now, I want to call the method from that class. But method name is read from some variable (basically I read method name from other location). When I use that variable it doesn’t work. I know sightly doesn’t allow expression inside an expression, so would like to know if there is an alternative to fit this need.

```
<sly data-sly-use.detailsModel="org.svc.core.model.DetailsModel"/>
```

`${detailsModel.{methodNameVariable}}` - doesn’t work (if the method name is read from some variable)
`${detailsModel.methodName}` -  works (if put the method name directly there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That really dependes on how you structured your data model and what you want to do with it.

If you want to do something like an `if ... else` that can be achieved with:

```
<sly data-sly-test="${condition}">${model.someMethod}</sly>
<sly data-sly-test="${!condition}">${model.otherMethod}</sly>
```

If you want to do something like a `switch ... case`:

```
<sly data-sly-test="${condition1}">${model.method1}</sly>
<sly data-sly-test="${condition2}">${model.method2}</sly>
...
```

If you want to have a trully dynamic method names then you’re better off with a model that returns a map of values instead of having a number of properties/methods and use the dynamic method name as a key:

```
${model.details[detailName]}
```